# How could i change the Text of an label by a function?

Tags: c#, winforms, function, button, label

I have a `Label` on my Windows Forms, and I want to change the `Text` of it by a `Button2_Click`, but only if an another `Button` *clicked before*.

**Example Code:**

```
bool var1 = false;
//the Label Example
label1.Text = "Noooh!";

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    function1(label1.Text);
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var1 = true;
}

private void function1(string Text)
{
    if (var1)
    {
        Text = "Yeaaah!";
    }
}
```

It should work like this, you need to click on the `button1 first`, after this you should click `button2` by this the `function1` should be *activated* and change the `label1` `Text` to `"Yeaaah!"`. The Code is *executed* in Visual Studio but the `label1` `Text` *doesn't change*, don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change function's (techically, we call it *method*, not *function*) *design*, pass `Control` (e.g. `label1`), not its `Text`:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we modify control...
    function1(label1);
}

private void function1(Control ctrl)
{
    if (var1)
    {
        // ... control's Text to be exact
        ctrl.Text = "Yeaaah!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

label1 is a Global Object, so no need to pass it as a parameter.

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    function1();
}

private void function1()
{   
    label1.Text = "New Title!";    
}
```